# QtCreator: Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?

Tags: c++, qt

I have opened a cmakelists.txt as a project in QtCreator under Windows 7. It compiles just fine and it produces a working executable in the right path. Only in the creator, the program wont start after building it. It always gives me the same error:

"Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
H:\path\to\my.exe exited with code -1"

As the path (I have double-checked) is right, and the executable is in the right place and runs fine, I was guessing the permissions were the problem.
I have tried running the creator as admin, which did not change anything.
I also tried changing the working directory in "Options- Build and Run - General"

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I am using QtCreator Qt Creator 3.3.1 Based on Qt 5.4.1, with a mingw compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to delete all the pro.user files from the project directory and then restarting Qt Creator and possibly reconfigure the projects?

Comment: As i stated, I open the project from a CMakeLists.txt file. In other words, it is a cmake project, not a qmake project. Therefore there are no .pro or .pro.user files. I have however imported the project several times from scratch without noticing any difference.